# Bootstrap clear-top with Nav-bar and different window size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I have on the top of my page a `.navbar-fixed-top` navigation, which works great after I added `padding-top: 25px` to the `<body>`. The problem is that when the window size goes below `980px`, the `padding` goes on the top of my `navbar` instead behind it and what I get is an ugly white empty space on the top. Any idea how to fix it?
EDIT: Thanks to simbirsk answer I just realized that except the fact that the "white space" appears my nav-bar is now no longer following the scroll when you scroll it is gone (it just stays at the top of the page). That is a problem too.

Comment: If you have a different issue you should open a new question. Anyway, answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

A fast solution: don't add that padding under the conflictive resolution. Change your CSS to this:

```
@media (min-width: 979px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
}
```

EDIT: For the new question.
That is the standard responsive behaviour. If you don't like how it works you can:

1. Not link `bootstrap.responsive.min.css`
2. Customize your Bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html
3. Write your own media queries

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it turns out there is one more problem which I discovered thanks to your answer. You can check the Edit of the question. Thanks!

Comment: Why is that the nav-bar is scrolling down with the view point on full screen or 980px+... I don't get the logic cause when I saw it on full screen to scroll down with the view point that was what I wanted. Yet is it suppose to not scroll as default?

Comment: Over 980px -> fixed. Under 980px -> not fixed. WHY? @markdotto explains it on Github: "Fixed on mobile isn't consistently possible, nor does it behave well—not even on iOS5. You're free to override that if you wish, but we won't be re-enabling until support is improved."

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now... well I suppose I'm going to stick with their decision and keep it that way, but really didn't know they explicitly made it that way. Thanks :)

Comment: But now with @media it doesn't work properly on full screen as the top part of the Body goes under the nav-bar... might need a bit more help ._.